# request.user as a choice in select widget in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model field

```
is_anonymous = BooleanField(default=False)
```

I also have a `ModelForm`. I want this field to be represented with a `select` widget.

It would be

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['is_anonymous']
        widgets = {
            'is_anonymous': forms.NullBooleanSelect(),
        }
```

It works. But I want the `select` widget to only have two choices `true` (1) and `false` (0) and the represented text in each option should be `Anonymous` for `true` and `self.request.user` for `false`.

I think I have to do this replacement in the views as `self.request.user` is not available in the `ModelForm`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you want, but if you want to display a select dropdown with only two choices; "Anonymous" which maps to True and "myusername" (i.e. the username of the current user) which maps to False, you need to override the `is_anonymous` field's widget's `choices` attribute:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['is_anonymous'].widget = forms.Select(choices=[
            (True, "Anonymous"),
            (False, user.username)
        ])

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['is_anonymous']
```

because we need the `user` object in our form, we need to pass it manually as a parameter when defining the form in our view. This depends on the type of view you are using, but assuming it's a generic class based `CreateView`, you need the following:

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = MyModelForm
    ...

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        return self.form_class(self.request.user, **self.get_form_kwargs())

    ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear but you understood exactly what I meant. Thank you :-)